# Does an array in Swift has any order?

Tags: arrays, swift, sorting

Why if I make an array and print it, prints it with a different order

The creation:

```
var array = [Int]();

array = [8, 1, 3, 4, 6, 5, 4, 7, 11 , 2, 10, 9];
```

The print method:

```
for i in array  {  

    print(array[i], terminator: ", ");

}
```

The Output:

```
11, 1, 4, 6, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 3, 10, 2,
```

Comment: To print the items in the array just use `print(i, terminator: ", ")`. You're using elements in the array as indices to access the array.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Arrays are, by definition, stably ordered.  Things come out in the the same order they go in.

In this case, you're iterating over the array, using the values in the array as indices:

```
for i in array {      // this line fetches each element from array in order,
                      //  ie., 8, 1, 3, 4, 6, ...
    print(array[i]...)   // this line indexes into array using the value you
                         // just fetched
}
```

If you just want to print the elements of the array, without the double-indexing, use:

```
for i in array {
    print(i, terminator: ", ")
}
```

Comment: One more thing, if the index is important as well as the value, you can iterate over both using `for (index, value) in array.enumerate() {` as suggested by Brian.

Answer (score 4):

`for i in array` walks through the *values* of an array, not its indices.  To walk over indices, use `enumerate`:

```
for (index, value) in array.enumerate() {
    print("array[\(index)]: \(value)", terminator: ", ")
}
```